# CRITICAL:pika.connection:Attempted to send frame when closed

Tags: python, websocket, rabbitmq, tornado, pika

I have used Pika to integrate the Websocket in Tornado and RabbitMQ. It sucessfully runs on various queues till some time. Then raises the following error:

CRITICAL:pika.connection:Attempted to send frame when closed

I have taken the code reference from `https://github.com/haridas/RabbitChat/blob/master/tornado_webapp/rabbit_chat.py`

I have gone through my code thoroughly, however fail to understand why it raises such an error.
Can someone help troubleshoot!

Thanks!

Also note changing the backpressure multiplier does not solve the problem. So looking for a real solution for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the consumers and producers were queuing - dequeuing from a particular queue, at a point PIKA Client just choked out due to the multiple asynchronous threading systems over the shared queue.

Thus, in case anybody else faces the same issue follow the several check ups in your code:

1. How many connections are you having? How many channels? how many queues? How many producers- consumers? (These could be determined by the sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues etc )
2. Once you understand the structure you are using, track the running transactions. For several requests by several users.
3. Thus on each transaction, print the thread action, so that you understand the pika activities. Since these threads run in async, if overwhelmed wrongly, causes the pika client to crash. Thus create a Thread Manager to control the threads.

Solution was advised by Gavin Roy & Michael Klishin, from Pika & RabbitMQ respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the pika connection just terminates because of a blip in the network. You should add code to the `PikaClient` class to handle reconnecting automatically when the connection goes down. Something like this (untested, but should give you the idea):

```
def on_connection_closed(self, connection, reply_code, reply_text):
    """This method is invoked by pika when the connection to RabbitMQ is
    closed unexpectedly. Since it is unexpected, we will reconnect to
    RabbitMQ if it disconnects.

    """
    self.channel = None
    if self._closing:  # Don't reconnect if you explicitly closed the connection.
        pass
    else:
        logger.warning('Connection closed, reopening in 5 seconds: (%s) %s',
                       reply_code, reply_text)
        self.connection.add_timeout(5, self.reconnect)

def reconnect(self):
    """Will be invoked by the IOLoop timer if the connection is
    closed. See the on_connection_closed method.

    """
    # Create a new connection
    self._reconnecting = True
    self.connection = self.connect()
```

Comment: It still provides the following warning and errors: 1)Pika: Write buffer exceeded warning threshold at 555752 bytes and an estimated 6861 frames behind. 2) ERROR:pika:TornadoConnection: Socket Error on 11: 104

Comment: @user3446151 1) is just a warning, it shouldn't actually cause problems. It's tough to say what 2) is. Are you running the chat example unchanged?

Comment: A few modifications here and there, but the queuing structure is the same , its not for a chat application which i require. Yeah I understand that its just a warning. However, the connection closes after the warning occurs in my case. Thus the messages stop flowing from producer to consumer.

Comment: @user3446151 You might want to file a bug at pika's github page: https://github.com/pika/pika. I've found the maintainer to be responsive in the past. Still, if you have reconnection logic in your code, you should be able to recover when that error occurs.